# Using @ModelAttribute for reference data - avoid binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'd like to use the autowiring magic of `@ModelAttribute` for obtaining and passing around reference data. The problem in doing this is that anything added to the model with `@ModelAttribute` is assumed to be a form backing object and then is bound to the request, potentially modifying the objects.

I simply want them added to the model for the view's reference and to be able to use the parameter level `@ModelAttribute` to wire objects into methods annotated with `@RequestMapping`. Is there a way to accomplish this without some verbose `@InitBinder` method?

for example:

```
@ModelAttribute("owner")
public Person getOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") Integer ownerId){
  return getOwnerFromDatabaseById(ownerId);
}

@RequestMapping("/{ownerId}/addPet.do")
public ModelAndView addPet(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("owner") Person owner){
  String name = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "name");
  Pet pet = new Pet();
  pet.setName(name);
  pet.setOwner(owner);
  saveToDatabase(pet);
}
```

A trivial example where a pet is added to an owner. I'd like to have the owner placed in the model to be used by the view, and i'd also like to make use of autowiring the parameter in `addPet()`. Assume both `Pet` and `Person` have a member `name`. In this case, `owner` will automatically get bound to the request, setting its `name` to the pet's name. How can this be avoided?

Comment: What do you mean by "assumed to be a form backing object"? Any examples of undesired behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong, in this case the @ModelAttribute should be Pet - that is what should be used as the form backing object.  To get he owner populated automatically based on the ownerId you can register a property editor for the Owner class that will have the logic you currently have in the getOwner method.

Comment: yeah i probably just need to do something completely different.